# simple CFG parser with epsilon transition

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar, cyk, earley-parser

I have stumbled upon many different algorithms(CYK and Earley) to check whether or not a string is part of the CFL whose CFG is provided. I am looking for something simple to understand and implement. What I need to know is if the string is in the CFG or not. The CFG is given usually in the form of

```
S->S1 S2
S1->S1 a | a
S2->S2 b | b
```

The solution is supposed to accept epsilon transitions as well eg S1-> a | e

any ideas?

Comment: So you found many different algorithms.  Why don't you try to implement one of them?

Comment: I believe they are more complicated and require certain type of input, they also don't support epsilon transitions.

Comment: 1) They aren't that complicated.  2) "require a certain type of input"; what special input do they require (you can't complain about such things without providing evidence).  3) I thought Earley's algorithm didn't mind epsilon rules.   Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_parser seems to claim ("alpha beta gamma ... [can be] the empty string") that the Earley algorithm allows rules with epsilon transitions.   A less generous person might think you haven't done your homework.

Comment: Testing if a string is a member of a language (CFL) is basically parsing.  Given you are starting from a grammar (CFG) you are making a parser generator.  There are dozens of parser generators out there and lots of research behind them.

Comment: I understand, but I was looking for a bruteforce approach furthermore a little easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a really straight forward approach on this project

https://code.google.com/p/cykparser/downloads/list

Unlike other CYK parsers that go through unnecessary validation of the grammar. This parser is a really good proof of concept that just implements the CYK algorithm with basic grammar.

The code is in python.